# Should the HTML title of this CrossValidated site still be "Statistical Analysis"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-name

Is it intentional that the HTML title for the CrossValidated site is "Statistical Analysis"?  Or is it a hold-over from the beta name?

The HTML title is what determines the browser window title and the default bookmark title, which makes things seems a bit out of sync.

EDIT: Just to clarify/expand after seeing mbq's answer, there are three prominent "names" for the site:

1. **stats.stackexchange.com**: domain name in URL
2. **Statistical Analysis**: HTML title used in browser title and bookmarks
3. **CrossValidated**: internal name used in page headers

I understand it's difficult to update a domain name (though not impossible), but I don't see why the HTML title (#2) shouldn't also be changed to "CrossValidated".

Comment: In fact the situation is a bit more complex -- crossvalidated.com is registered and works as a synonym to stats.stackexchange.com; on the other hand Statistical Analysis works as the name on SE-wide pages like stackexchange.com, data explorer, blog, etc...

Comment: And I know what you meant; I just hope that your post may be an impulse to rethink and settle this stuff.

Comment: @mbq, by editing my question, I didn't mean to suggest a misunderstanding in your answer. It's just that your secondary point motivated me to clarify that my question is not about whether CV or SA is a good name.

Answer (score 6):

As I understand, the general idea of SE team is just make everything a *topic*.stackexchange.com to build a StackExchange brand. Statistical Analysis outside and CrossValidated inside is a kind of *status quo* -- the same is with cooking, which is internally SeasonedAdvice, and Apple being AskDifferent.
I like CrossValidated as a name and I'm of course glad of this compromise, but honestly I don't know what are its terms, thus I don't know what are the odds of moving it in any direction.

Anyway I'll repeat the most utilitarian reason why CV is better than Stats -- this is not a site about Statistical Analysis, but about statistical analysis, designing experiments, collecting data, data mining, machine learning, visualizing data, probability theory, mathematical statistics and statistical and data-driven computing. The only short statement to cover it is "data science", but on the other hand this collides with SE data explorer.
BTW the "Q&A for statisticians, data analysts, data miners and data visualization experts" line reflects the wide scope already, and it looks somewhat strange written below "Statistical Analysis"...

Answer (score 3):

A few months ago, we went and updated most of the HTML for the named sites. Now, `Cross Validated` should appear in the title text of the page / in the tab you have the site open in.

Comment: Nice work, thanks!